# Connect to EC2 SQL with MySQLWorkbench

Tags: amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL instance on an Amazon EC2 instance. I set up the necessary bind address and can synchronize with it using my local `PhpMyAdmin` app.

However, any other method of connecting to the remote server fails. This includes MySQLWorkbench, MySQL command line and JDBC.

The only difference I can tell is there is a `socket` field in `PhpMyAdmin` that is not configured in any of there others. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually solved it, though I still don't know what the problem is. Even though `PhpMyAdmin` was connecting, it didn't do anything.

I followed the article here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

and make a new user with privileges on that database and it connected with the new user. Still doesn't connect with root.

Also, for anyone else stumbling on this you might wanna try the method below. It's more secure.
http://masdel.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/connecting-your-toad-for-mysql-to-amazon-aws-ec2-using-ssh-tunneling/